# Converting a CSV to RDF where one column is a set of values

Tags: csv, rdf, semantic-web, linked-data, sparql-generate

I want to convert a CSV to RDF.

One of the column of that CSV is, in fact, a set of values joined with a separator character (in my case, the space character).

Here is a sample CSV (with header):

```
col1,col2,col3
"A","B C D","John"
"M","X Y Z","Jack"
```

I would like the conversion process to create a RDF similar to this:

```
:A :aProperty :B, :C, :D; :anotherProperty "John".
:M :aProperty :X, :Y, :Z; :anotherProperty "Jack".
```

I usually use Tarql for CSV conversion.
It is fine to iterate per row.
 
But it has no feature to sub-iterate "inside" a column value.

SPARQL-Generate may help (with iter:regex and sub-generate, as far as a I understand). But I cannot find any example that matches my use case.

PS: may be RML can help too. But I have no prior knowledge of this technology.

Answer (score 6):

You can accomplish this with [RML](https://rml.io) and [FnO](https://fno.io).

First, we need to access each row which can be accomplished with RML. 
RML allows you to iterate over each row of the CSV file (`ql:CSV`) with a 
[LogicalSource](https://rml.io/specs/rml/#logical-source).
Specifying the [iterator](https://rml.io/specs/rml/#iterator) (`rml:iterator`) 
is not needed since the default iterator in RML is a row-based iterator.
This results into the following RDF (Turtle):

```
<#LogicalSource>
    a rml:LogicalSource;
    rml:source "data.csv";
    rml:referenceFormulation ql:CSV.
```

The actually triples are generated with the help of a [TriplesMap](https://rml.io/specs/rml/#triples-map) which 
uses the LogicalSource to retrieve the data from each CSV row:

```
<#MyTriplesMap>
    a rr:TriplesMap;
    rml:logicalSource <#LogicalSource>;

    rr:subjectMap [
        rr:template "http://example.org/{col1}";
    ];

    rr:predicateObjectMap [
        rr:predicate ex:aProperty;
        rr:objectMap <#FunctionMap>;
    ];

    rr:predicateObjectMap [
        rr:predicate ex:anotherProperty;
        rr:objectMap [
            rml:reference "col3";
        ];
    ].
```

The `col3` CSV column be used to create the following triple:

```
<http://example.org/A> <http://example.org/ns#anotherProperty> "John".
```

However, the string in the CSV column `col2` needs to be split first.
This can be achieved with Fno (Function Ontology) and an RML processor which
supports the execution of FnO functions. Such RML processor can be the 
[RML Mapper](https://github.com/RMLio/rmlmapper-java), but other processors can 
be used too. 
The following RDF is needed to invoke an FnO function which splits the input 
string with a space as separator with our LogicalSource as input data:

```
<#FunctionMap>
    fnml:functionValue [
        rml:logicalSource <#LogicalSource>; # our LogicalSource
        rr:predicateObjectMap [
            rr:predicate fno:executes; 
            rr:objectMap [ 
                rr:constant grel:string_split # function to use
            ];
        ];
        rr:predicateObjectMap [
            rr:predicate grel:valueParameter;
            rr:objectMap [ 
                rml:reference "col2" # input string
            ];
        ];
        rr:predicateObjectMap [
            rr:predicate grel:p_string_sep;
            rr:objectMap [ 
                rr:constant " "; # space separator
            ];
        ];
    ].
```

The supported FnO functions by the RML mapper are available here: 
https://rml.io/docs/rmlmapper/default-functions/
You can find the function name and its parameters on that page.

**Mapping rules**

```
@base <http://example.org> .
@prefix rml: <http://semweb.mmlab.be/ns/rml#> .
@prefix rr: <http://www.w3.org/ns/r2rml#> .
@prefix ql: <http://semweb.mmlab.be/ns/ql#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix fnml: <http://semweb.mmlab.be/ns/fnml#> .
@prefix fno: <https://w3id.org/function/ontology#> .
@prefix grel: <http://users.ugent.be/~bjdmeest/function/grel.ttl#> .
@prefix ex: <http://example.org/ns#> .

<#LogicalSource>
    a rml:LogicalSource;
    rml:source "data.csv";
    rml:referenceFormulation ql:CSV.


<#MyTriplesMap>
    a rr:TriplesMap;
    rml:logicalSource <#LogicalSource>;

    rr:subjectMap [
        rr:template "http://example.org/{col1}";
    ];

    rr:predicateObjectMap [
        rr:predicate ex:aProperty;
        rr:objectMap <#FunctionMap>;
    ];

    rr:predicateObjectMap [
        rr:predicate ex:anotherProperty;
        rr:objectMap [
            rml:reference "col3";
        ];
    ].

<#FunctionMap>
    fnml:functionValue [
        rml:logicalSource <#LogicalSource>;
        rr:predicateObjectMap [
            rr:predicate fno:executes; 
            rr:objectMap [ 
                rr:constant grel:string_split 
            ];
        ];
        rr:predicateObjectMap [
            rr:predicate grel:valueParameter;
            rr:objectMap [ 
                rml:reference "col2" 
            ];
        ];
        rr:predicateObjectMap [
            rr:predicate grel:p_string_sep;
            rr:objectMap [ 
                rr:constant " ";
            ];
        ];
    ].
```

**Output**

```
<http://example.org/A> <http://example.org/ns#aProperty> "B".
<http://example.org/A> <http://example.org/ns#aProperty> "C".
<http://example.org/A> <http://example.org/ns#aProperty> "D".
<http://example.org/A> <http://example.org/ns#anotherProperty> "John".
<http://example.org/M> <http://example.org/ns#aProperty> "X".
<http://example.org/M> <http://example.org/ns#aProperty> "Y".
<http://example.org/M> <http://example.org/ns#aProperty> "Z".
<http://example.org/M> <http://example.org/ns#anotherProperty> "Jack".
```

**Note**: I contribute to RML and its technologies.

Answer (score 2):

You can test this query on the playground https://ci.mines-stetienne.fr/sparql-generate/playground.html and check it behaves as expected:

```
BASE <http://data.example.com/> 
PREFIX : <http://example.com/> 
PREFIX iter: <http://w3id.org/sparql-generate/iter/>
PREFIX fun: <http://w3id.org/sparql-generate/fn/>

GENERATE { 
  <{?col1}> :anotherProperty ?col3.
  GENERATE{
      <{?col1}> :aProperty <{ ?value }> ; 
  }
  ITERATOR iter:Split( ?col2 , " " ) AS ?value .
}
ITERATOR iter:CSVStream("http://example.com/file.csv", 20, "*") AS ?col1 ?col2 ?col3
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Tabular Data Model](https://www.w3.org/TR/2015/REC-tabular-data-model-20151217/) and related specs target this use case, although as I recall, we didn't provide for combinations of `valueUrl` and `separator` to have sub-columns generate multiple URIs.

The metadata to describe this would be something like the following:

```
{
  "@context": "http://www.w3.org/ns/csvw",
  "url": "test.csv",
  "tableSchema": {
    "columns": [{
      "name": "col1",
      "titles": "col1",
      "datatype": "string",
      "required": true
    }, {
      "name": "col2",
      "titles": "col2",
      "datatype": "string",
      "separator": " "
    }, {
      "name": "col3",
      "titles": "col3",
      "datatype": "string",
      "propertyUrl": "http://example.com/anotherProperty",
      "valueUrl": "http://example.com/{col3}"
    }],
    "primaryKey": "col1",
    "aboutUrl": http://example.com/{col1}"
  }
}
```