# RML and FnO fails to run together

Tags: csv, sparql, rdf, linked-data, rml-rdf

I am trying to use FnO functions in RML mapper (I like to do a `string_split` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53715353/converting-a-csv-to-rdf-where-one-column-is-a-set-of-values)).
This is how my folder looks like:

[image]

I am executing `java -jar "rmlmapper.jar" -m mapping-cuisines.ttl -o output-cuisines.ttl -s turtle`

However, when I try implementing a `<#FunctionMap>` i get the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
        at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
        at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:372)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:458)
        at be.ugent.rml.functions.DynamicMultipleRecordsFunctionExecutor.execute(DynamicMultipleRecordsFunctionExecutor.java:66)
        at be.ugent.rml.functions.AbstractSingleRecordFunctionExecutor.execute(AbstractSingleRecordFunctionExecutor.java:17)
        at be.ugent.rml.termgenerator.LiteralGenerator.generate(LiteralGenerator.java:42)
        at be.ugent.rml.Executor.generatePredicateObjectGraphs(Executor.java:157)
        at be.ugent.rml.Executor.executeWithFunction(Executor.java:115)
        at be.ugent.rml.Executor.execute(Executor.java:76)
        at be.ugent.rml.cli.Main.main(Main.java:206)
```

Nothing makes sense to me. According to the git repo, the functions are loaded dynamically from where i execute the rmlmapper.

Dataset: https://mega.nz/file/LsJAQRaR#84lfASPXVA08zm0RbuRfNvR7tx-vklS82D1KBGhhdA8

My Code:

```
@base <http://example.org/data> .
@prefix ex: <http://example.org/ns#> .
@prefix rr: <http://www.w3.org/ns/r2rml#> .
@prefix rml: <http://semweb.mmlab.be/ns/rml#> .
@prefix ql: <http://semweb.mmlab.be/ns/ql#> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix csvw: <http://www.w3.org/ns/csvw#> .
@prefix fnml: <http://semweb.mmlab.be/ns/fnml#> .
@prefix fno: <https://w3id.org/function/ontology#> .
@prefix grel: <http://users.ugent.be/~bjdmeest/function/grel.ttl#> .


<#LogicalSource>
    a rml:LogicalSource;
    rml:source "dataworld-restaurants-cuisines.csv";
    rml:referenceFormulation ql:CSV.


<#MyTriplesMap>
    a rr:TriplesMap;
    rml:logicalSource <#LogicalSource>;

    rr:subjectMap [
        rr:template "http://example.org/{id}";
    ];

    rr:predicateObjectMap [
        rr:predicate ex:aProperty;
        rr:objectMap <#FunctionMap>;
    ].

<#FunctionMap>
    fnml:functionValue [
        rml:logicalSource <#LogicalSource> ;
        rr:predicateObjectMap [
            rr:predicate fno:executes ;
            rr:objectMap [ rr:constant grel:toUpperCase ]
        ] ;
        rr:predicateObjectMap [
            rr:predicate grel:valueParameter ;                  
            rr:objectMap [
                rml:reference "spicy"                           
            ]
        ]
    ] .
```

My functions.ttl:

```
@prefix dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/> .
@prefix doap:    <http://usefulinc.com/ns/doap#> .
@prefix fno:     <https://w3id.org/function/ontology#> .
@prefix fnoi:    <https://w3id.org/function/vocabulary/implementation#> .
@prefix fnom:    <https://w3id.org/function/vocabulary/mapping#> .
@prefix grel:    <http://users.ugent.be/~bjdmeest/function/grel.ttl#> .
@prefix grelm:   <http://fno.io/grel/rmlmapping#> .
@prefix rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .

grel:toUpperCase a fno:Function ;
  fno:name "to Uppercase" ;
  rdfs:label "to Uppercase" ;
  dcterms:description "Returns the input with all letters in upper case." ;
  fno:expects ( grel:valueParam ) ;
  fno:returns ( grel:stringOut ) .

grelm:javaString
    a                  fnoi:JavaClass ;
    doap:download-page "GrelFunctions.jar" ;
    fnoi:class-name    "io.fno.grel.StringFunctions" .

grelm:uppercaseMapping
    a                    fnoi:Mapping ;
    fno:function         grel:toUpperCase ;
    fno:implementation   grelm:javaString ;
    fno:methodMapping    [ a                fnom:StringMethodMapping ;
                           fnom:method-name "toUppercase" ] .
```

Comment: I can't see if you also registered the functions in a Turtle file to the corresponding JAR file and Java class as mentioned here: https://github.com/RMLio/rmlmapper-java#including-functions

Comment: I created a functions.ttl file (see changes above). Still, the same error remains.

Comment: Works well for me with https://github.com/RMLio/rmlmapper-java/releases/download/v4.9.2/rmlmapper-4.9.2.jar

Comment: I already tried importing this .jar. Could you upload a minimal .zip with all files where FnO functions works for you? Haven't found a single repo yet to try out..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried out your mapping file and it works correctly.
Your current mapping file transforms the data in the `spicy` to upper case
and generates the specified RDF triples.
Since the function `grel:toUpperCase` is included in the RMLMapper by default,
you don't need to `functions.ttl` to specify these functions.
This is only necessary if you want to add your own custom functions.
An overview of all included functions in the RMLMapper can be found here: https://rml.io/docs/rmlmapper/default-functions/

## Given example

1. Download the latest RMLMapper from our Github repository: https://github.com/RMLio/rmlmapper-java/releases
2. Run it as: `java -jar <path to jar> -m mapping.rml.ttl`
3. I get the output which is listed below.

**mapping.rml.ttl**

```
@base <http://example.org/data> .
@prefix ex: <http://example.org/ns#> .
@prefix rr: <http://www.w3.org/ns/r2rml#> .
@prefix rml: <http://semweb.mmlab.be/ns/rml#> .
@prefix ql: <http://semweb.mmlab.be/ns/ql#> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix csvw: <http://www.w3.org/ns/csvw#> .
@prefix fnml: <http://semweb.mmlab.be/ns/fnml#> .
@prefix fno: <https://w3id.org/function/ontology#> .
@prefix grel: <http://users.ugent.be/~bjdmeest/function/grel.ttl#> .


<#LogicalSource>
    a rml:LogicalSource;
    rml:source "dataworld-restaurants-cuisines.csv";
    rml:referenceFormulation ql:CSV.


<#MyTriplesMap>
    a rr:TriplesMap;
    rml:logicalSource <#LogicalSource>;

    rr:subjectMap [
        rr:template "http://example.org/{id}";
    ];

    rr:predicateObjectMap [
        rr:predicate ex:aProperty;
        rr:objectMap <#FunctionMap>;
    ].

<#FunctionMap>
    fnml:functionValue [
        rml:logicalSource <#LogicalSource> ;
        rr:predicateObjectMap [
            rr:predicate fno:executes ;
            rr:objectMap [ rr:constant grel:toUpperCase ]
        ] ;
        rr:predicateObjectMap [
            rr:predicate grel:valueParameter ;                  
            rr:objectMap [
                rml:reference "spicy"                           
            ]
        ]
    ] .
```

**Output (truncated)**

```
<http://example.org/afghani> <http://example.org/ns#aProperty> "NO".
<http://example.org/african> <http://example.org/ns#aProperty> "YES".
<http://example.org/african_portuguese> <http://example.org/ns#aProperty> "YES".
<http://example.org/american> <http://example.org/ns#aProperty> "NO".
<http://example.org/andhra> <http://example.org/ns#aProperty> "YES".
<http://example.org/arabian> <http://example.org/ns#aProperty> "NO".
<http://example.org/arabian_lebanese> <http://example.org/ns#aProperty> "NO".
<http://example.org/arabian_mexican> <http://example.org/ns#aProperty> "NO".
<http://example.org/arabian_middle_eastern> <http://example.org/ns#aProperty> "YES".
<http://example.org/asian> <http://example.org/ns#aProperty> "YES".
<http://example.org/assamese> <http://example.org/ns#aProperty> "NO".
<http://example.org/australian> <http://example.org/ns#aProperty> "YES".
<http://example.org/awadhi> <http://example.org/ns#aProperty> "YES".
<http://example.org/awadhi_mughlai> <http://example.org/ns#aProperty> "NO".
<http://example.org/bakery> <http://example.org/ns#aProperty> "NO".
```

## FnO string_split

If you want to use a FnO's `string_split` in RML, you can achieve it like this:

1. `fno:executes`: `grel:string_split` to use the GREL split function.
2. `grel:valueParameter`: the input string you want to split.
   I referenced here to the CSV column `cuisines`.
3. `grel:p_string_sep`: the string separator on which the GREL split function
   must split the input string.
   I used  `,` here to separate the different cuisines for each restaurant.

**mapping.rml.ttl**

```
@base <http://example.org> .
@prefix rml: <http://semweb.mmlab.be/ns/rml#> .
@prefix rr: <http://www.w3.org/ns/r2rml#> .
@prefix ql: <http://semweb.mmlab.be/ns/ql#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix fnml: <http://semweb.mmlab.be/ns/fnml#> .
@prefix fno: <https://w3id.org/function/ontology#> .
@prefix grel: <http://users.ugent.be/~bjdmeest/function/grel.ttl#> .
@prefix ex: <http://example.org/ns#> .

<#LogicalSource>
    a rml:LogicalSource;
    rml:source "dataworld-restaurants-cuisines.csv";
    rml:referenceFormulation ql:CSV.


<#MyTriplesMap>
    a rr:TriplesMap;
    rml:logicalSource <#LogicalSource>;

    rr:subjectMap [
        rr:template "http://example.org/{id}";
    ];

    rr:predicateObjectMap [
        rr:predicate ex:cuisine;
        rr:objectMap <#FunctionMap>;
    ];
.

<#FunctionMap>
    fnml:functionValue [
        rml:logicalSource <#LogicalSource>;
        rr:predicateObjectMap [
            rr:predicate fno:executes; 
            rr:objectMap [ 
                rr:constant grel:string_split 
            ];
        ];
        rr:predicateObjectMap [
            rr:predicate grel:valueParameter;
            rr:objectMap [ 
                rml:reference "cuisines" 
            ];
        ];
        rr:predicateObjectMap [
            rr:predicate grel:p_string_sep;
            rr:objectMap [ 
                rr:constant ", ";
            ];
        ];
    ].
```

**Output (truncated)**

```
<http://example.org/afghani> <http://example.org/ns#cuisine> "Afghani".
<http://example.org/african> <http://example.org/ns#cuisine> "African".
<http://example.org/african_portuguese> <http://example.org/ns#cuisine> "African".
<http://example.org/african_portuguese> <http://example.org/ns#cuisine> "Portuguese".
<http://example.org/american> <http://example.org/ns#cuisine> "american".
<http://example.org/andhra> <http://example.org/ns#cuisine> "Andhra".
<http://example.org/arabian> <http://example.org/ns#cuisine> "Arabian".
<http://example.org/arabian_lebanese> <http://example.org/ns#cuisine> "Arabian".
<http://example.org/arabian_lebanese> <http://example.org/ns#cuisine> "Lebanese".
<http://example.org/arabian_mexican> <http://example.org/ns#cuisine> "Arabian".
<http://example.org/arabian_mexican> <http://example.org/ns#cuisine> "Mexican".
<http://example.org/arabian_middle_eastern> <http://example.org/ns#cuisine> "Arabian".
<http://example.org/arabian_middle_eastern> <http://example.org/ns#cuisine> "Middle Eastern".
<http://example.org/asian> <http://example.org/ns#cuisine> "Asian".
<http://example.org/assamese> <http://example.org/ns#cuisine> "Assamese".
<http://example.org/australian> <http://example.org/ns#cuisine> "Australian".
<http://example.org/awadhi> <http://example.org/ns#cuisine> "Awadhi".
<http://example.org/awadhi_mughlai> <http://example.org/ns#cuisine> "Awadhi".
<http://example.org/awadhi_mughlai> <http://example.org/ns#cuisine> "Mughlai".
<http://example.org/bakery> <http://example.org/ns#cuisine> "bakery".
<http://example.org/bar_food> <http://example.org/ns#cuisine> "Bar Food".
<http://example.org/bar_food_brazilian> <http://example.org/ns#cuisine> "Bar Food".
<http://example.org/bar_food_brazilian> <http://example.org/ns#cuisine> "Brazilian".
```

**Note**: I work on RML and FnO technologies